# insert into table1 select * from another table2 , then delete the row from table2

Tags: sql, oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to  insert rows into table1 select * from table2 and finally delete the rows from table2  using function in oracle sql developer. I am not getting how to do it.

follwing is my function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION DELETEROW(GODOWN_DIST_CODE IN 
TEST_TABLE.GODOWN_DIST_CODE%TYPE)  return varchar2
AS
returned_value varchar2(50);
BEGIN
begin
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE_BACKUP SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE 
GODOWN_DIST_CODE=GODOWN_DIST_CODE;
DELETE TEST_TABLE WHERE GODOWN_DIST_CODE = GODOWN_DIST_CODE;

INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE_BACKUP SELECT * FROM NEW_TABLE WHERE GODOWN_DIST_CODE 
= GODOWN_DIST_CODE;
DELETE FROM NEW_TABLE WHERE GODOWN_DIST_CODE = GODOWN_DIST_CODE;

exception
 WHEN no_data_found THEN
      returned_value := '#';
end;
RETURN returned_value;    
END;
```

Comment: Show the audience what you had tried so far which is not working or giving wrong result.

Comment: You `can not` use `RETURN` inside `PROCEDURE`. You need to create `FUNCTION` if you want to return something. `FUNCTION` and `PROCEDURE` are two different things.

Comment: @XING, I have created above function, when I execute the function all the rows are getting inserted to TEST_TABLE_BACKUP  and NEW_TABLE_BACKUP , but I am passing parameter with some value and used it as where condition, even all records are getting deleted.

Comment: @KeyurPanchal, I have updated my function, When I execute the function with parameter all the rows are getting insert to backup table and delete all the rows from main table, but without using the where cluase, Can you please tell what mistake I am doing.

Comment: @BharathPateru. Why are you after `FUNCTION` when your requirement demands a `PROCEDURE`. We generally use function where are in need of some calulation or want some logical or boolean value to be returned. You can follow what's show in below examples.

Comment: @XING, I need a confirmation that my function has did run successfully, that's why I am changed to function

Comment: @BharathPateru. You can then write a `DBMS_OUTPUT` to see if your procedure worked or not. Thats not a big deal. Or incase you only want to use `FUNCTION` then inplace of `DBMS_OUTPUT` write your fucntion to return `#` if not success.

Comment: @XING, I don't know about DBMS_OUTPUT, if I able to get returned value with using DBMS_OUTPUT in java class then definitely I'll try to write it. I s it possible to get returned value in java?

Comment: @XING, I am passing a parameter based on this I am inserting to another table and deleting from actual table, as per your answer I am not able to do it. I want to execute the function by returning a value. I am working on that. I am grateful to you.

Comment: @BharathPateru. Why you cannot do it . I guess i changed nothing in the input parameter to procedure. I only added a `return` which is `OUT` incase of procedure. Ofcourse you need to tweek my answer to match your requirement but alltogether the base should be same,

Comment: And what will happen if new rows are inserted into table TEST_TABLE while you are backing it up? Why, you will delete these rows as well. You have to make sure you are deleting only rows that you have backed up.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    NEW_PURCHASE_RECORD_DL(GODOWN_CODE IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE_BACKUP SELECT * FROM 
    TEST_TABLE WHERE GODOWN_DIST_CODE=GODOWN_CODE;
    DELETE FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE 
    GODOWN_DIST_CODE=GODOWN_CODE;
     
    INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE_BACKUP SELECT * FROM 
   NEW_TABLE WHERE GODOWN_DIST_CODE=GODOWN_CODE;
   DELETE FROM NEW_TABLE WHERE 
  GODOWN_DIST_CODE=GODOWN_CODE;
   COMMIT;
  RETURN 'done';
  END NEW_PURCHASE_RECORD_DL;

Comment: @Goran Stefanović, above comment(function) is working correctly, but it always returns done, how can I change the return value.

Comment: @XING, above comment(function) is working correctly, but it always returns done, how can I change the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion, i propose this solution for you. Even though i dont find any need of having a `FUNCTION` am showing the exmaple using a `FUNCTION`. Also I had written your delete logic to a `Procedure` and depending on the success of delete statement, a `Return` value is caputured in variable `var` and sending as OUT `paramater` which you can use.

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION confirm_ckh
   RETURN VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN ('#');
END;
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETEROW (
   GODOWN_DIST_CODE   IN TEST_TABLE.GODOWN_DIST_CODE%TYPE,
   var OUT varchar2) <-- Out parameter to get the return value
AS

BEGIN
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE_BACKUP
         SELECT *
           FROM TEST_TABLE
          WHERE GODOWN_DIST_CODE = GODOWN_DIST_CODE;

      IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Insert Success TEST_TABLE_BACKUP');
         var:=confirm_ckh;
      END IF;

      DELETE TEST_TABLE
       WHERE GODOWN_DIST_CODE = GODOWN_DIST_CODE;

      IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Deleted records from TEST_TABLE ');
         var:=confirm_ckh;
      END IF;


      INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE_BACKUP
         SELECT *
           FROM NEW_TABLE
          WHERE GODOWN_DIST_CODE = GODOWN_DIST_CODE;

      IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Insert Success for NEW_TABLE_BACKUP');
         var:=confirm_ckh;
      END IF;

      DELETE FROM NEW_TABLE
            WHERE GODOWN_DIST_CODE = GODOWN_DIST_CODE;

      IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Deleted records from NEW_TABLE ');
         var:=confirm_ckh;
      END IF;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         null;
   END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLE2_TO_TABLE1
  IS
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TABLE1(
              Field1,
              Field2,
              Field3
              )
            SELECT Field1,
                  Field2,
                  Field3
                  FROM TABLE2';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE TABLE2 where rownum != 0';
 END TABLE2_TO_TABLE1;
```

Execute Procedure

```
BEGIN
    TABLE2_TO_TABLE1;
END;
/
```